# How to debug macro-generated methods in Xcode/LLDB?

Tags: xcode, lldb

I have a few methods that are generated by a macro. I can see the code in the "preprocess" companion, it compiles and runs fine. I can step through the disassembly, but that's no fun. It also seems that a similar problem exists for multiple statements that are written on a single line. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are hard to debug, as you are experiencing.

That is because they are expanded before compilation starts (by the preprocessor), so by the time clang/gcc/icc/whatever sees your code, and then generates debug info for it, including line tables, there is no trace left of the macro.

The problem is not LLDB-specific and is more generally due to the nature of the C/C++/ObjC compilation model with a preprocessor and then a separate compiler, where only the latter contributes to debug info generation and only the former sees macros.

Comment: I realise this, but Xcode has a companion tab for preprocessor-output code. I'd expect to be able to debug *that*, at least.

Comment: Basically, the rule is that you will be able to debug whatever source code the compiler sees and emits debug information for. In the presence of macros, I would expect that line tables could not exactly match your source code, esp with multi-line macros. I am not sure what the UI story is with the Preprocessed output code. If you feel Xcode could do better, you can definitely file such a request at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I guess I will, then. A follow up question: can the LLDB debug multiple statements that live on a single line? Because that's also something I couldn't get Xcode to do.

Comment: I believe currently clang does not emit line tables that include column information. Lacking that information, and according support in LLDB and Xcode UI, the debugger will highlight the entire source code line repeatedly, so you should actually be able to step through your several statements, but most probably not able to see each one highlighted separately.

Comment: I can live without flying cars, but no macro debugging? Sadness :-(